# await without declaring function as async

Tags: asynchronous, dart, language-design

Actually in Dart, in order to use `await` in function body, one need to declare whole function as `async`:

```
import "dart:async";

void main()  async {
  var x = await funcTwo();
  print(x);  
}

funcTwo() async {
  return 42;
}
```

This code wouldn't work without marking `main()` as `async`

```
Error: Unexpected token 'await'.
```

But, doc says "The `await` expressions evaluates `e`, and then **suspends** the currently running function until the result is ready–that is, until the Future has completed" ([Dart Language Asynchrony Support](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async))

So, maybe I miss something, but there is no need to force function to be asynchronous? What is a rationale for making async declaration obligatory ?

Comment: Most languages adopting `async` and `await` chose the same design: C#, Python, JavaScript, Dart, etc. And they chose it for the same reasons; see [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html) for an early collection of alternatives and why they weren't chosen. Your particular question is under the `Inferring “async”` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `async` functions `await` is rewritten to code where `.then(...)` is used instead of `await`.

The `async` modifier marks such a function as one that has to be rewritten and with that `await` is supported.

Without `async` you would have to write

```
void main() {
  return funcTwo().then((x) {
    print(x);  
  });
}
```

This is a very simple example but the rewriting can be rather complex when more of the async features are uses, like `try`/`catch`, `await for(...)`, ...

Comment: So it comes from implementation detail ? I imagine that it could be theoretically rewritten something like `void main()  {
  future = funcTwo();
  while (future.notCompleted){} 
  x = future.result;
  print(x);  
}`

Comment: That would be busy-waiting and cause your CPU to get hot and the battery empty ;-) Dart works with an event queue like JavaScript in the browser instead of busy waiting.

Comment: Yes, I know, this exemple is a huge simplification.  I am just wondering if async really needs to be propagated upstream.

Comment: Async is a unified API for passing callbacks, like you do with `then(...)`. If you think this through you'll see there is no way around propagating it upstream. It was discussed that there would technically be a way with multiple stacks, but because the browser doesn't support that, Dart also does not.

Comment: The "Without `async` you would have to write" part is a bit confusing since you use `async` in the example.

Comment: I see. I was sloppy. My intention was to remove that. Thanks for the hint - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that `await` was not originally part of the Dart language.  To maintain backward compatibility with existing programs that could potentially use `await` as an identifier, the language designers added a mechanism to explicitly opt-in to using the new `await` keyword: by adding a (previously invalid) construct to declare a function `async`.