# Dart: async abstract method

Tags: dart

I'm trying to design an interface that abstracts long-running operation that should not be used from UI directly. To abstract it, I've created an abstract class with the only method to perform such an operation:

```
abstract class MakeSomething {

  Result make(Param param);

}
```

However I can't mark it as `async` (tried to place in before the signature, before the return type and before the semicolon). Is it possible, and, if yes - how?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`async` functions almost always must return a `Future`. (An uncommon exception is `async` functions may have a `void` return type to be "fire-and-forget"; in such cases, there is no automatic way for the caller to be notified when the function completes.)

If you want your `make` function to be asynchronous and to provide a `Result` to the caller, it must return `Future<Result>`.

Note that `async` is not part of the function's type signature; `async` is a contextual keyword that [*enables* the use of `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54634939/179715) inside the body of the function.  That means that `async` is not very useful when declaring an abstract interface.  The important part is that the function returns a `Future`, and derived classes can choose whether to implement that function using `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the compile error "A function body must be provided. Try adding a function body":

[image]