# Is there anyway I could pass an async funtion as a parameter to a constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to assign an async function to an instance variable.
I have tried:

```
class TextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  late String message;
  late bool isPass;
  late Function(String?) callback;

  TextBox(String message, bool isPass, Future<dynamic> Function(String?) async func) {
    this.message = message;
    this.isPass = isPass;
    this.callback = func;
  }
}
```

But get the following exception:

```
Expected to find ')'
```

I know why I get the error. I just dont know the proper syntax to do this in dart.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55749913/.  What makes a function asynchronous is whether it returns a `Future`. The `async` keyword  just enables the use of `await` in the function body; it's an *implementation* detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code:

```
  final Future<void> callback;
```

You can change the void type to any data type you want.

Comment: but dont i have to mark it as async for it to be async? or does return a future make it an async function

Comment: You should pass an "async function" to TextBox but there is no need to put async in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the keyword `async` because making the function return a `Future` is enough.
Also, you can write a constructor without a body.

```
class TextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final String message;
  final bool isPass;
  final Future<dynamic> Function(String?) callback;

  TextBox(this.message, this.isPass, this.callback);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  late String message;
  late bool isPass;
  late Future<String> data;

  MyHomePage(this.message, this.isPass, this.data);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String getData = '';

  @override
  MyHomePage get widget => super.widget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('$getData Test Demo'),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }

  getFutureData() async {
    getData = await widget.data;
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

**Achieve like this  have used String you can use your custom class**