# How to make a nested httpClient call, multiple async / awaits in Dart

Tags: dart, async-await

I have to make a few calls using httpClient.  One of them gets the 'main' data for a given blog post in json format, and with that info I then have to make a second call for additional media info related to that post.

This is all for multiple posts, so in essence I'm doing:

```
Future<List<String>> fetchPosts() async {
  response = await httpClient.get('http://somewebsite/topPosts');
  data = json.decode(response.body) as List;
  data.map((singlePost) {
    mediaID = singlePost["mediaID"];
    //second await call below, this won't work as-is, correct?
    finalData = await httpClient.get('http://somewebsite/media/$mediaID')
```

I hope that makes sense, what I'm trying accomplish.  Essentially I'm nesting http calls.  Not sure of a 'good' way of doing this, maybe something with `Future.wait()`, any advice welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
 data.map((singlePost) {
    mediaID = singlePost["mediaID"];
    //second await call below, this won't work as-is, correct?
    finalData = await httpClient.get('http://somewebsite/media/$mediaID')
```

Isn't going to work.  First, you're using `await` in the callback supplied to `map`, but [`await` can be used only in a function marked `async`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633277/await-without-declaring-function-as-async).

After you mark the callback with `async`, the code probably doesn't do what you want. `List.map()` is used to *transform* a `List`.  For example, you'd use it to create a list of `String`s from a list of `int`s or vice-versa.  In this case, you'll be generating a list (actually an `Iterable`) of `Future`s.  You don't store that list of `Future`s anywhere, and therefore you can't ever `await` them to be notified when they complete.

What you might is something like:

```
final futures = data.map((singlePost) async { ... });
await Future.wait(futures);
```

And that would wait for *all* operations to complete.  However, you'll have another problem in that your `map` callback does:

```
finalData = await httpClient.get('http://somewebsite/media/$mediaID')
```

which means that each callback will clobber the `finalData` variable (whatever that is) in some unspecified order.